# AWS Lambda Node Js - Increment value if exist else add element

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want increment value if exist else add element.

```
+-----------------------+
| id | iteration | data |
+-----------------------+
| 10 |         1 | foo1 |
| 11 |         1 | foo2 |
| 12 |         2 | foo3 |
+-----------------------+
```

my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({'region': 'eu-west-1'}); 
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

var params = {
  Item: {
    id: uuid,
    iteration: 1,
    data: body.data
  },
  TableName: "my-table"
};

documentClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
      const errResponse = {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ Error: 500, device : "DynamoDB", detail : err })
      };
      callback(null, errResponse);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", params.Items);
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("thanks")
      };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  });

}
```

My insert is OK.

I try with:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "my-table",
    Key:{
        "id": uuid
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set iteration = iteration + :val",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":val": 1
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
  };
  documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        const errResponse = {
          statusCode: 500,
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ Error: 500, device : "DynamoDB", detail : err })
        };
        callback(null, errResponse);
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify("thanks")
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
  });
```

Update is OK (increment -> 2)

But I want increment value **ONLY** if exist else **ONLY** add element. Both methods are asynchronous, how should I do?

Comment: Can you have one "upsert" function which inside a transaction will check if the record exists and if not create it otherwise update the iteration? I'm not familiar with DynamoDB but basically you need to check for the record/create/update in a transaction.

Comment: @maschaub, I understand what to do, I ask how to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your 2nd answer is close.  In your `UpdateExpression` you need both and `ADD` and a `SET` on the same line.  like the following:

```
    UpdateExpression: "ADD iteration :iteration SET itemdata = :itemdata",
```

This is formally documented in the [AWS DOCS for UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax) under DynamoDB
scrolling down it says

> ADD - Adds the specified value to the item, if the attribute does not
>   already exist. If the attribute does exist, then the behavior of ADD
>   depends on the data type of the attribute:
>   If the existing attribute is a number, and if Value is also a number,
>   then Value is mathematically added to the existing attribute. If Value
>   is a negative number, then it is subtracted from the existing
>   attribute.

I was able to find a [AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=239939) that had a successful upsert, as well as another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387846) with the ADD and SET syntax in the same line.  Below is some code that will run if placed in a new lambda (change your region to match where your table is)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({'region': 'eu-central-1'});

exports.handler = function(item, context, callback) {

    var params = {
        TableName: "my-table",
        Key:{
            "id": item.id
        },
        UpdateExpression: "ADD iteration :iteration SET itemdata = :itemdata",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ':iteration': 1,
            ':itemdata' : item.data
        },
        ReturnValues:"NONE"
};

documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
      const errResponse = {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ Error: 500, device : "DynamoDB", detail : err })
      };
      callback(null, errResponse);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", params.Items);
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("upsert complete.")
      };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  });
};
```

**note:**  data is a reserved keyword, and I got the following error:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data
```

consider changing it to something else.  I used `itemdata`.

Running it once will insert a new record.  The following images are before and after images of the table after I run the lambda the second time.
[image]
[image]